# Modifying an object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

I have an object of the following kind:

```
{ body: { entry: { body: '' }, context: '' },
  contextids: 
   [ { uid: 'ff992fa0-817a-11e4-bea0-299f5e3c3819',
       name: 'deemeetreesNotebook' },
     { uid: 'ff992fa1-817a-11e4-bea0-299f5e3c3819', name: 'public' },
     { uid: 'ff992fa2-817a-11e4-bea0-299f5e3c3819', name: 'ideas' },
     { uid: 'ff992fa3-817a-11e4-bea0-299f5e3c3819',
       name: 'thingsToLearn' },
     { uid: 'ff992fa4-817a-11e4-bea0-299f5e3c3819',
       name: 'wayToRussia' },
     { uid: 'ff992fa5-817a-11e4-bea0-299f5e3c3819',
       name: 'polysingularity' },
     { uid: 'ff992fa6-817a-11e4-bea0-299f5e3c3819',
       name: 'infranodus' },
     { uid: 'ff992fa7-817a-11e4-bea0-299f5e3c3819',
       name: 'artmital' } ],
  internal: 1 }
```

I want to reiterate through this object, and modify it in the way that it only keeps the `contextids` where `name` equals a certain string (e.g. `thingsToLearn`).

What is a good way to remove unwanted contextids from my original object?

Thanks!

Comment: Use [**`Array#filter`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Comment: ^ that, `contextids` is an array !

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/0hjc7dgL/

Answer (score 1):

Loop, check, splice:

```
var nameToKeep = "someId";
for (var i = 0; i < data.contextids.length; i++) {
    if (data.contextids[i].name != nameToKeep) {
        data.contextids.splice(i, 1);
        i--;
    }
}
```

Comment: The only things I would change about this answer would be to write it functionally and write `data.contextids[i].name !== nameToKeep` in the if statement, because `!==` is best practice

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
var d = {
  body: {
    entry: {
      body: ''
    },
    context: ''
  },
  contextids: [{
    uid: 'ff992fa0-817a-11e4-bea0-299f5e3c3819',
    name: 'deemeetreesNotebook'
  }, {
    uid: 'ff992fa1-817a-11e4-bea0-299f5e3c3819',
    name: 'public'
  }, {
    uid: 'ff992fa2-817a-11e4-bea0-299f5e3c3819',
    name: 'ideas'
  }, {
    uid: 'ff992fa3-817a-11e4-bea0-299f5e3c3819',
    name: 'thingsToLearn'
  }, {
    uid: 'ff992fa4-817a-11e4-bea0-299f5e3c3819',
    name: 'wayToRussia'
  }, {
    uid: 'ff992fa5-817a-11e4-bea0-299f5e3c3819',
    name: 'polysingularity'
  }, {
    uid: 'ff992fa6-817a-11e4-bea0-299f5e3c3819',
    name: 'infranodus'
  }, {
    uid: 'ff992fa7-817a-11e4-bea0-299f5e3c3819',
    name: 'artmital'
  }],
  internal: 1
};

d.contextids = d.contextids.filter(function(item) {
  return item.name === "thingsToLearn";
  });

alert(JSON.stringify(d.contextids));
```